# Is there a way to convert DOCX to Google Docs directly in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

Before, Google Docs would automatically convert Word files when you open it using the *"Open with > Google Docs"* command on Google Drive.

But recently, it updated to allow native editing of Office files. So now I have to open .docx files with Google Docs, *and then* select *"File > Save as Google Docs"* just to convert .docx into Google Docs format.

Is there a faster way to do this?

**Note:** Simply switching to Google Docs is not an option, as we still heavily use Word in our organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Converter for Drive Document** or **Save Cloud files to Google Drive** by adding it to your Drive:

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

---

Also, there is an option in Drive settings:

[image: 0]